# Java 8 return from Optional Map

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, option-type

I have a code segment as follows:

```
class MyObject{
   Set<AnotherObject> mySet;
   public Set<MyAnotherObject> getMySet(){
   // getter code
   }
}

if ( myObject.getMySet().isEmpty() ) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    else {

        MySecondObject mySecObj = new 
       MySecondObject(myObject.mySet().findFirst.get().value);
        return Optional.of(mySecObj);
    }
```

How can I convert it into an Optional Map idiomatic manner to get rid of the if-else block?

Comment: What's the type of `myObject.mySet()`? I'm not aware of anything in standard Java that has a member variable named `findFirst`, and if it's your own class, then you'll need to post its code too.

Comment: Can you show us the full code and full types please so we can understand what you want exactly?

Comment: it should be: myObject.mySet().stream().findFirst()

Comment: `myObject.mySet().stream().findFirst().map(o -> o.value).map(MySecondObject::new) `

Comment: That works. Thanks!